# c# console Make sure user typed a password

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application

Sorry if the question is noobish, didnt know to google for what and found nothing, i have a **console application** that get a password from user and will set it on a file. i want to be sure that user typed a password and **don't leave it blank** (just pressed Enter). and if he didn't typed anything
the application ask him again and again for password **until he enter somthing**.

```
bool isitempty = true;
while (isitempty)
{
    var passwordFile = Console.ReadLine();
    if (passwordFile == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sorry, type again");
    }
    else
    {
        zip.Password = String.Format("{0}", passwordFile);
    }
    isitempty = false;
}
```

I ran this but it just ask one time and if user again leave it blank it will pass this step.

Comment: Try moving the `isitempty = false;` statement up into the `else` block.

Comment: Move isitempty = false; inside the else clause.

Comment: haha thanks fixed. @Lasse V. Karlsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change to your code to fix your issue would be to move the `isitempty = false;` statement up into the `else` block:

```
    ....
    else
    {
        zip.Password = String.Format("{0}", passwordFile);
        isitempty = false;
    }
}
```

---

A "better" (in my opinion) rewrite would be to restructure the code like this:

```
string passwordFile = string.Empty;
while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordFile))
{
    passwordFile = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordFile))
        Console.WriteLine("sorry, type again");
}
zip.Password = passwordFile;
```

This way:

- You don't have an extra variable to keep track of, it is the password variable you need to keep track of and check
- You don't need `string.Format` when your format is just `{0}`, simply use the parameter directly (as long as it is a string that is)

**Note** one change that I made to your code, I interpreted "must enter something" as "don't allow only spaces either". If this is incorrect, and the password can indeed contain only spaces, you should replace both occurrences of

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordFile)
```

with this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordFile)
```

**Double note**: If you have .NET Framework older than 4.0, you must use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` as `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was first introduced in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Agreed, fixed so both statements have the same logic.

Comment: why it give me error on "IsNullOrWhiteSpace", says:string does not contain definition for"IsNullOrWhiteSpace".

Comment: Did you copy and paste or did you write `IsNullOrWhitespace` (notice lowercase `s` in `space`?

Comment: @AidenStewart what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @MattJones Yeah, oops, might be an older .NET framework version in play here.

Comment: So great. thank you

Comment: It's likely a typo, given that he posted a typo. `IsNullOrWhitespace` has been in .Net since 2.0; if he's a beginner it seems unlikely to me he'd be starting out with something older than that.

Comment: Since 4.0 according to the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string password = null;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password));

    // do something with the password
}
```

Comment: I never found a use for the 'ugly' do while, this still isn't one of them.

Comment: FYI, I removed my upvote because you are missing the "oops" message

Comment: @musefan I don't see the reason why the `do-while` loop is "ugly" and why you shouldn't use it: different coding preferences *do* allow you to achieve the same goal (the code in my answer is identical to the one in the accepted answer).

Comment: @musefan Also both loops get translated to almost identical IL with the exception of an unconditional jump in the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: It's ugly because you have to wait until the end to work out what the logic for looping is. Anyway, it's preference. But what is fact is that you are not doing that same as accepted answer. What part of you code outputs `"sorry, type again"` as per OP question?

Comment: @musefan Outputting message to the user is a minor implementation detail which I left out for simplicity. Logically the code is identical.